# In the Android app "Lua Interpreter" I want to extract wiki text on demand

Tags: curl, lua

In the Android app "Lua Interpreter" I want to extract wiki text on demand.
I'm going to use the additional system command "curl".

```bash
curl -s "https://uk.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&titles=%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%82%D0%B8" > "/storage/emulated/0/iGO_Pal/save/wiki_data.lua"
```

It works in TerMux" for Android successfully. **Only one thing: the target file must exist!!**
Request
https://uk.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&titles=%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%82%D0%B8
successful in the browser.

If I try to use this request

```lua
os.execute('curl -s "https://uk.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&titles=%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%82%D0%B8" > "/storage/emulated/0/iGO_Pal/save/wiki_data.lua"')
```

in the Lua interpreter - nothing happens.
The file is just empty.
All necessary permissions are in the Lua interpreter!
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The system can't find the path
"/storage/emulated/0/iGO_Pal/save/wiki_data.lua"
check the path
or give storage permission to "curl".

PS: "%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0% D1%85%D1%82%D0%B8" - has an unnecessary space